# Impossibility result on metric learning?

Tags: machine-learning, st.statistics

Are there any fundamental limitations (impossibility results) known for [metric learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_learning)?

Are there any direct connection reduction from/to that I can use results in clustering? (e.g. [this](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kleinber/nips15.pdf): [2](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kleinber/nips15.pdf) )

[2](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kleinber/nips15.pdf) Kleinberg, Jon. "An impossibility theorem for clustering." Advances in neural information processing systems (2003): 463-470.